# Jquery video will not re-play

Tags: jquery, ipad, video, mobile-safari, jplayer

I am making a small activity for a website that requires a video to be played. At the end of the video, I need to be able to replay the video on a button click. exe -

```
$('#thought_bubbs').click(function(){
    $("#jp").jPlayer("play")
});
```

Everything works exceptionally well, except on mobile safari. On the ipad (which is the problem device specifically,) after the video has played once, I cannot get the video to play again. On the second play event I only get a black video box.
Is there a way to refresh only Jplayer? I have found that the .load doesnt make a difference on the ipad.

Comment: Someone has to know something right? I have scoured the net but cant seem to find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Did you find the answer for your question because I am also struggling with the same issue. If you have the answer now please share.